# Banner and Sign

Tags: synonyms

I still remember I had a question about whether a **sign** can be referred to as **banner**?

In an old game I played, Diablo, there was this quest "[Ogden's Sign (Quest)](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Ogden%27s_Sign_(Quest))" where a sign is referred to as a *"magic banner"* by one foul creature "[Snotspill (Fallen One)](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Snotspill)".

So my question is: **Can a sign be referred to as a banner?**

Dictionaries don't give information on that **banner** is a synonym of **sign**!

Comment: I think of physical [banners](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banner) as pieces of cloth. Physical signs, however, could be made from any material - stone, cloth, metal, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Ogden's Sign" quest, a creature has stolen the sign from the tavern because it has the image of a sun on it, and some other creatures have in turn stolen it from him. The creature calls it a "magic banner" instead of a magic sign, because he intends to use it as a war standard. If you give the sign to the creature he says:

> *"You give! Yes, good! go now, we strong! We kill all with big magic! (laughs)"* From [Diablo Wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Snotspill)

[image: the tavern sign] The image of the tavern sign shows it as hanging from a pole, so it could be carried like a [standard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standard), or *"a conspicuous object (as a banner) formerly carried at the top of a pole and used to mark a rallying point especially in battle or to serve as an emblem."* Something like this:

[image: a Warhammer 40K figure carrying a standard]

A banner in this sense is not interchangeable with sign, because it is more symbolic than a simple sign. "They marched under the White Queen's sign." wouldn't make people picture the same thing as "They marched under the White Queen's banner." A banner (in this context) is a symbol of something that people might rally around. A sign (in the sense of a tavern sign) is just an informational display.

A related idiom is "[under the banner of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/under-the-banner-of)" something, which Collins dictionary explains as

> If someone does something under the banner of a particular cause, idea, or belief, they do it saying that they support that cause, idea, or belief.

For example (from Collins dictionary),
*Russia was the first country to forge a new economic system **under the banner** of Marxism.*

Another related idiom is "[standard bearer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/standard-bearer)", which Collins dictionary describes as

> If you describe someone as the standard bearer of a group, you mean that they act as the leader or public representative of a group of people who have the same aims or interests.

For example,

*The opposition has also been wracked by infighting since the February death of longtime **standard bearer** Etienne Tshisekedi.*
<sup>(Source: [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-congo-politics-idUSKBN17C1NC) )</sup>

Comment: So Snotspill implies a different meaning to the sign which makes it a magic banner while Ogden, the Inn keeper, sees it only as a physical object.

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

A [banner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banner) (see def. 3) is one type of [sign](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign) (see def. 5a). Sign is a more general term.

Banner has many definitions. When used as in the example given, and compared to a sign, the appropriate definition from Merriam-Webster is:

> a strip of cloth on which a sign is painted

Sign has many definitions. When used as in the example given, and compared to a banner, the appropriate definition from Merriam-Webster is:

> a display (as a lettered board or a configuration of neon tubing) used to identify or advertise a place of business or a product

In the examples given by the OP, a sign is a marking, with graphics and/or text, designed to communicate some information.

In the examples given by the OP, a banner is a marking, with graphics and/or text, *on a flexible display like cloth,* designed to communicate some information.